# Colon use, em dash, or comma

Tags: punctuation, commas, colons, em-dashes

What is the proper way to punctuate this sentence? Colon, em dash, or comma?

> - Eating at a homeless shelter since March has provided me with a look into the thoughts of other people: both the homeless themselves
>     and their friends.
> - Eating at a homeless shelter since March has provided me with a look into the thoughts of other people — both the homeless themselves
>     and their friends.
> - Eating at a homeless shelter since March has provided me with a look into the thoughts of other people, both the homeless themselves
>     and their friends.

Also, is there supposed to be a comma between "themselves" and "and"?

Comment: After reading that post, I'm still a little confused. You could classify that as a list, so I then I should probably use a colon right? But then I would also need to use a comma to separate the list?

Comment: Any is acceptable here (though the colon comes across as a little stuffy). The dash signals a longer pause (for contrast, or thought). The comma is optional, but I wouldn't include it if you've already chosen to use one after 'people'.

Answer (score 0):

All three are correct, but I would personally choose the comma.

Oxford comma should not be used for that sentence (between "themselves" and "and") as you are only referring to two groups.